# Get Rownum Attribute as a Transient Attribute in Oracle ADF

Tags: oracle-adf, rownum

I have a requirement, in which the code is using a SQL as

```
Select <COLUMN_LIST>, ROWNUM from <TABLE_LIST_AND_WHERE_CLAUSE>;
```

Now i need to remove this ROWNUM from the Select list but still keep the functionality of the attribute.

I have tried forums but with no fruit.

Please suggest is i can use an EL or an attribute to do the same.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Will adding #{vs.index + 1} for getting row number in your table solve your problem . vs would be your varStatus attribute value in `<af:table>` ?

Answer (score 1):

You can't get the value of a column from nowhere. If you remove the ROWNUM from the select query you can not get its values anymore. If you just want to have an attribute called ROWNUM as transient, you can give a certain value to it from EL but however not the original column name, unless you get that value from a SELECT in another place and put it there. But why do you want to have it removed at all? If you don't want to get it displayed anywhere you can change its Display property to FALSE and you should be fine.

Comment: The SQL is performing bad due to the rownum. The usage that  found was sort of getting dynamic row sequence number. so wanted to know if there is any other way to get that dynamic row sequence number so that i can improve the query performance

Comment: I can't think of a solution to this, but I think you may add a column in the database table (ex: RID as Number) and increment it on insert by a trigger as Oracle till 12c doesn't support autoincrement. Hope you will figure out something. Tung